# fulfilling a function of an ArrayList of object type by using foreach loop

Tags: java, oop, arraylist

I'm just trying to use a function in the main code which is written Category class. e.g.

```
Arraylist<Category> categories = new Arraylist<>();
// ArrayList has been filled with objects.
for (Category category : categories) {
    categories.get(building).someFunction();
}
```

I know .get's parameter should be integer index but my arraylist is of an object type. How can I check all elements of the arraylist by using foreach loop?

Comment: Do you want to invoke `someFunction()` for every list element with foreach ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I want to use same function for all of the elements of the arraylist

Comment: `for (Category category : categories)` will iterate through each element of `categories`. You don't need to call method `get`. Is `someFunction()` a method in class `Category`?

Comment: @mustafalinan What is building?

Comment: Yes Abra! This method is in my Category class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use category object in place of categories list inside for loop.

```
Arraylist<Category> categories = new Arraylist<>();
// ArrayList has been filled with objects.
for (Category category : categories) {
    category.someFunction();
}
```